# What are some practical applications for adding a timer to your python code?

Tags: python, timer

I'm new to Python and trying to apply the lessons being taught (online) but unfortunately, I don't understand why they are asking for timer code. In your experience, why have you added timer code to your program? Can you give me some practical examples so I can better understand why?

Sorry if it's a dumb question - TIA.

Comment: What is "timer code"?

Comment: What do you mean by a "timer code"? Anyways, please provide a [mcve], and asking for examples is off-topic for SO. You should visit the [help/on-topic] and [ask] to see which types of questions can be asked here.

Comment: Sorry - don't have code to post (still learning how to write it) but I didn't understand why they were asking for this                                                     
Using Time and Sleep Functions
To time your code you will need to:
    First, create a variable that records the start time (start_time), the point you 
    want to start timing your code
    Next, create a variable that records the stop time (end_time), the point you 
    want to stop timing your code
    Finally, to calculate the total runtime (tot_time) by subtracting the start_time 
    from end_time

Comment: That's a bad recommendation. To properly measure your code's efficiency use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers are often added in lesson code to show the difference between different coding options. i.e., there are more than one ways to do it, but which is fastest? You wouldn't run the code in production.

Comment: Thank you! That's a practical application I can apply ....